# Two lovers who met on a train & met again 10 years still in love & with a 9-year old daughter

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this film on TV in the 1980s. Two young people met on a train and fell in love. They wanted to marry each other. However, the man's father had already arranged that he marry his partner's daughter. The young lover therefore could not keep an appointment with his lover who wanted in vain for him at a cafe in what appears to be Paris.

Ten years later, on a train, both of them meet again. The woman has a daughter: the man is divorced. They fall in love again but the woman angrily decides to move on. The man discovers her daughter is 9 years old and guesses she is his daughter. Desperate, he begins a crazy race to catch up with the train. Failing, he stumbles to the same cafe where he was supposed to have met his lover 10 years before. There, he finds his lover and their daughter and they reconcile.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the TV movie [Romance on the Orient Express](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089932/combined) from 1985 with Cheryl Ladd.

> Lily, an American traveling on the famous Orient Express train from Venice to Paris, suddenly runs into her former lover, Alex, whom they met and had a tender romance 10 years earlier while vacationing in France which ended abruptly when he walked out on her without saying a word. Now Alex tries to make up for lost time with Lily while she digs into his past to find out what haunting secrets that he has which led to their abrupt breakup.

Alex left back then because his father wanted him to marry someone else, and Lily's daughter is secretly Alex's. Here's the promo: